# Problem with adding a new post type

Tags: localization

I want to add a new post type

i have a php file (posttype.php) at : wordpress/wp-content/themes/

this is the code :

```
<?php
// Add new post type for Recipes
add_action('init', 'cooking_recipes_init');
function cooking_recipes_init() 
{
    $args = array(
        'label' => _x('Recipes'),
        'singular_label' => _x('Recipe'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments')
    ); 
    register_post_type('recipes',$args);
}
?>
```

i have a problem at the top of the page (but the posttype is created suc) :

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for _x(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\posttypes.php on line 12 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 189

Warning: Missing argument 2 for _x(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\posttypes.php on line 14 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 189
```

Thank you .

Comment: put that code INTO the theme, not outside...(/wp-content-themes/YOURTHEME/functions.php ) is a better practice to place into functions. If you code doesn't have erros, it should work

Answer (score 1):

`_x()` requires a context, either remove it completely or set it to something like 'Recipe Singular' and 'Recipe Plural'.

Docs: [`_x()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x)

Answer (score 1):

Labels need two necessary arguments i.e. $text and $context.

This is your code which contain 1 argument which is $text and you need to add the second argument.

```
$args = array(
    'label' => _x('Recipes'),
    'singular_label' => _x('Recipe'),
```

Code with both arguments will look like this.

```
$args = array(
    'label' => _x('Recipe', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_label' => _x('Recipe', 'post type general name'),
```

For detail explanation about custom post type please visit [here](http://www.wpmemorize.com/2013/custom-post-type-in-custom-wordpress-theme/)